# Parse iOS SDK: Adding a non-Facebook friend into an array of Facebook friends

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I have an app where users can log on with Facebook as well as username and password. I have a feature in the app that allows users to search for each other to be added to each user's friends list. I can do this and it all works fine. Problem is when I populate the friends into a table view with friends name and picture. Friends who use Facebook get their info from from a URL request...

```
//viewDidLoad
    NSString *accessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;
    NSString *surl = @"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@&fields=picture,name,first_name,last_name";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:surl, accessToken]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *d, NSError *e) {

        if (e==nil) {

            friendData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:d options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

            friends = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:friendData[@"data"]];

            NSLog(@"%@", friends);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [friendTableView reloadData];
            });
        }

        else {

            //there are errors


        }

//cellForRowAtIndexPath
    NSString *url = friendsDictionary[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"];
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

while users who do **not** use Facebook get their info loaded in via PFQuery...

```
//query method thats called in viewDidLoad
    PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
    [postQuery whereKey:@"postedByID" containedIn:@[userId]];
    [postQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        self.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

}];
```

How can I query a user's Facebook friends as well as their other friends who do not use Facebook and populate the same tableView?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try append each users array to one general array, like, in your table view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *tableData;

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)getPeopleFromFacebook
{
    __weak ZIFacebookFriendsTableViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [ZIFBHelper getUsersWithTheAppInstalledWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSArray *friends, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"[ERROR] - %s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], error.userInfo]);
        }

        if (succeeded) {
            weakSelf.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:friends]
            [ZIFBHelper getFacebookFriendsWithoutTheAppInstalledWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSArray *friends, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"[ERROR] - %s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], error.userInfo]);
                }

                if (succeeded) {
                    weakSelf.tableData = [weakSelf.tableData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:friends]
                    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` method you can call this `getPeopleFromFacebook` get the users with facebook, the users without facebook and join both arrays in just one (`tableData`), this array is the one that you use as the data source of your table view controller.